# jQuery switchStyle unwanted behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why when I execute

```
function przygotuj_Highlighter() {
    $(".ELEMENT_LISTY").mouseenter(function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).switchClass("", "HIGHLIGHT", 400, "easeInOutQuad");
    });
    $(".ELEMENT_LISTY").mouseleave(function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).switchClass("HIGHLIGHT", "", 400, "easeInOutQuad");
    });
}
```

Firebug says:

- When page loaded `<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY DODAJ"></div>`
- When function fired `<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY DODAJ HIGHLIGHT"></div>`
- When mouseleave fired `<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY DODAJ" style></div>` (when copied and pasted from Firebug it looks like `<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY DODAJ" style=""></div>` but Firebug itself shows it as `style` with no `=""`

Why this "style" is added? I dont want that trash in my code!

Answer (score 0):

`switchClass` is actually part of jQuery UI, not base jQuery.

While it's doing the transition, it dynamically modifies the style, and it needs to restore it when it's done. There's no difference between `style`, `style=""` and no style attribute, so it doesn't bother to detect this special case.

It's not making a change to your code, it's just updating the DOM.

Comment: Im trying to debug this becaouse it slows down when got more than 100 elements.